# Is treating others decently more important than keeping Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hashkafah-philosophy, bein-adam-lachavero

Two questions:

1. According to Jewish philosophy which is more important in Judaism,
   keeping Shabbos, or treating others decently?
2. According to Jewish practical law, which is more important?

Comment: How do you define more important

Comment: what is treating others decently? not stealing?

Comment: @doubleAA@ray Anything that can be considered "bein Adam lechaveiro".

Comment: @doubleAA I mean someone who breaks Shabbos is not counted for a minyan, pouring wine, eidus halachically, but someone who steals/gossips/treats others unfairly is still considered fine for all the aforementioned.

Comment: I can't write for the life of me but for a source see Mishnah Torah hilchos rotzaich 4:7-8 for some thoughts.     Also if someone is bothered by your keeping shabbos maybe they need to attend a diversity course...

Comment: @mroll  at the diversity thing

Comment: @Don To be clear your asking which is more important where importance is measured by how many of testifying, pouring wine and counting in a Minyan a violator can perform? So don't you already have your answer?

Comment: @doubleAA I was having this discussion with a friend and mentioned that story with an amorah whom when asked to teach the Torah on "one foot" pretty much said "treat others as you'd want yourself to be treated",  "hamevayesh chaveiro b'rabim ein love cheilek..." and  "derech eretz kadmah latorah.."

Comment: @Don Why did you just tell me that?

Comment: @doubleAA ...so why would keeping Shabbos have such strongs repercussions, while bein adam lemakom (stealing for example) is not even thing when it comes to kashrus / minyan

Comment: @Don if that's why what you want to know then why didn't you just ask it above? No one forced you to write something you don't want. Just ask what you want to know. Beating around the bush with ambiguous terminology and unclear background doesn't help anyone address your concerns. You should edit to clarify asap

Comment: That is a fair point. I am pretty sleep deprived, but dully noted.

Answer (score 5):

See the commentary of the רא"ש - Rosh, on Mishna Peah 1:1  -פאה פרק א' משנה א'
.

> כי הקדוש ברוך הוא חפץ יותר במצות שיעשה בהם גם רצון הבריות מבמצות שבין
>   אדם לקונו:
>
> Hashem prefers those mitzvos which also accomplish the will of people,
>   more than the mitzvos between man and his Creator.

Comment: the world "also" implies has both types together. not that between man and man is better than between man and Gd

Comment: @ray Your noting of the word "also" is correct. But your deduction is incorrect. Since ALL Mitzvos which are between man and man are always ALSO  between man and Gd  , since they are Gd's will.

Comment: You have a strange habit of finding one source that proves the point and completely ignoring all others. I wonder why people like it, as it is completely off the Halacha?

Comment: @AlBerko 1- I dont ignore others. If I would know of others I would quote them. 2- In this subject all the others only bring ideas, and possible deductions,, not clear sources. I was the only one who brought a source which clearly gives an answer to this specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

**None of the בין אדם לחבירו overrides Shabbos.** There are a couple of reasons:

1. Mitzvot are ordered hierarchically according to their punishments. There's no way of transgressing Shabbos with the capital/corporal punishment for a באל"ח Mitzvah that is either ממונות with no punishment but repay or general Mitzvah of Chesed that can be forgiven (the reason we don't say blessings on those Mitzvos).
2. The Gemmorah in Kiddushin 30 is clear about preferring Shabbos over כיבוד אב based on the Pasuk "איש אביו ואמו תיראו ושבתותי תשמרו אני ה'". The reasoning is simple - since both of you have to respect Shabbos there's no way of performing a באל"ח by transgressing Shabbos. Please note that כיבוד אב is thought to be a very important Mitzvah comparable with honoring Hashem.
3. Shabbos is called ברית ("את בריתי תשמורו"). Keeping Shabbos is a way of testifying that Hashem created the world etc... None of the באל"ח Mitzvos is called ברית.
4. Shabbos has both Do and Don't parts, where most of the באל"ח are only Dos and we have the rule (Rosh Hashana 32) Do's don't override Dos with Don'ts. *THere's a long dispute there to understand why Shabbos is so serious.*

---

*Clarification: as with כיבוד אב, there's no clear-cut between those two types as ALL of the באל"ח include באל"מ, also all life-threatening Mitzvos (murder or life-saving) are more באל"מ as a man is created to resemble Hashem's. **So those two do override Shabbos**.*

Comment: Is לא תעמוד על דם רעך not a Bein Adam Lechavero?

Comment: @DoubleAA Simply - one cannot forgive on that, just like murder, as I stated in clarifications - that makes it באל"מ! If one begs you to kill him and promises he will forgive - can you kill him? THerefor it is not באל"ח. The very definition is that one can forgive, be it ממונות or חסד or אבידה which is also ממונות etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's really a tough question. On the one hand a person is defined in their religiosity by whether they keep shabbos or not but on the other hand both are mitzvos and pirke avos tells us not to distinguish between mitzvos. I don't think either are more important than one another but they address different sides of the spectrum of what it means to be a religious Jew

Comment: I’m not sure how this answers the question. Unlike the other answer, this is just an unsourced opinion and doesn’t really help anyone.